# So much memory being used and programs disappearing Mac OS

Tags: macos, memory

My computer is saying that too much memory is being used and is shutting down randomly. The only few programs I run are League occasionally, Skype and Parallels Desktop. I have 8GB on RAM and here is a screenshot of my Activity Monitor.

In addition, my computer force restarted because of an error recently and some question marks have appeared in the taskbar. Is my computer memory becoming corrupted? It says 7.7GB of memory are being used... but not even that much memory is being used (you can add it up). Any ideas?

**Picture of my Activity Monitor:**

[image: Picture of my Activity Monitor]

**Picture of my Taskbar:**

[image: Picture of my Taskbar]

Comment: The `?` icon is what the Dock shows when the application/file/whatever it pointed to no longer exists. If you deleted some application, but did not remove the Dock icon, it would show this the next time the Dock launches.

Comment: Thanks! Its possibly the reason (Maybe I was freeing up some disk space and forgot). Any idea on the memory usage?

Comment: This answer on Ask Different might help you understand total memory usage: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/36068/70505 Info might be outdated though.

Comment: I would be suspect of the `java` process running as `root`. I'd run `ps aux | grep 'java'` in Terminal, and see what it is that's running.

Comment: testcomputer:~ Clinder$ ps aux | grep 'java'
root              187   0.0  2.8  2891160 236684   ??  S     8:42PM   0:46.69

@ Alexander O'Mara

Whats the correct command to kill this process? I've tried 'kill 187'

Comment: Oh Sudo Kill 187 :) Unfortunately that has not decreased the memory usage by much

Answer (score 0):

If you're running a VM inside Parallels desktop it is possible, that this VM is allocating too much memory (8GB is not much, if you're running e.g. Windows 7 or 10 on a VM). To find out: Shut down your VM and go to the settings of the VM, where you can adjust the allocated memory partition for your VM.